# converting single column csv into multiple column csv using python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

**the code I have given below will convert and API response into a CSV file, but its dumping entire response of the API into once column, but I need in different columns with the header of
'SKU', 'Category_name', 'price', 'specialPrice', 'sizes', 'offers'**

> > > > the data inside is object, object, float64, float64, object(this is the sizes we have to mention, the thing is its a list), object,
> > > >         and entire thing is in list

```
import requests
import json
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

my_data = {
"category_ids" : "948",
"limit" : "10000"
}

my_headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.post('https://newapi.zivame.com/api/v1/catalog/list', data=json.dumps(my_data),
                     headers=my_headers)


data = response.json()
products = data.get("data").get("docs")
x=products.get(0)
dataList = []



for product in products:
    valuepack = product.get("valuePackOffers",None)
    offer = []
    if valuepack:
        for v in valuepack:
            offer.append(v.get("display_name",None))
    #ts = datetime.now().timestamp()
    #datatime_data = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)


    dataList.append([product.get("sku",None), product.get("mainCategoryName",None), product["price"], product["specialPrice"], product.get("sizes",None), offer])

len(dataList)




with open(r'/home/arcod/Downloads/data.json','w') as js:
    json.dump(dataList, js)


#import pandas
#from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
#data1 = json.load('/home/arcod/Downloads/data.json')
#norm_data = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(data1))
#import os
#os.open(r'/home/arcod/Downloads/test.csv','w')
#norm_data.to_csv('/home/arcod/Downloads/test.csv')

import csv

with open(r'/home/arcod/Downloads/promos_zivame.csv','w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerows(dataList)


import pandas as pd

dl = pd.read_csv('/home/arcod/Downloads/promos_zivame.csv','wb', delimiter=",", error_bad_lines=False)
dl.dtypes
print(dl.dtypes)
new_dl = pd.DataFrame()

index = 1
for i in range(0, len(dl)):
    new_dl['' + str(index)] = dl[0].iloc[i:i+10].reset_index(drop=True)
    index +=1

print(new_dl)



print('Done')
```

Comment: Please only submit the code that is relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of saving `dataList` as json , why can't you save it as a `csv` file.

```
import pandas as pd
dl = pd.DataFrame(dataList, columns = ['SKU', 'Category_name', 'price', 'specialPrice', 'sizes', 'offers'])
dl.to_csv('/home/arcod/Downloads/promos_zivame.csv')
```

Comment: im getting an panda,hash exception after running this

Comment: what is the full trace of exception?

Comment: that exception got resolved the thing if you run the code a CSV file will be created with only one column and without a header, now I need to split one column into multiple columns, with the relevant data, for instance, I need all SKU's in one column, and all prices in another column like I need different columns, and 
thank you in advance please help me out!

Comment: this code does the same, replace all the code after creating the `dataList` with this code , this will give the desired output

Comment: yeah, but i need in that way can you help me out

Comment: i don't know what the error is, try to open the csv using microsoft excel or open office with delimiter=`,`, or directly save to an excel file using `dl.to_excel('/home/arcod/Downloads/promos_zivame.xls',index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

## changes in your csv writing function

```
import csv

with open(r'/home/arcod/Downloads/promos_zivame.csv','w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(('SKU', 'Category_name', 'price', 'specialPrice', 'sizes', 'offers'))
    writer.writerows(dataList)
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not working i have tried here the internal data is object i want in different columns

Comment: what error you are having could you send me code full trace of exception

Comment: could  you send me output

Comment: if you run the code, you will get a csv file with only one column csv, but i need to split one column into multiple columns with the proper headers

Comment: could you provide me your mail id so that i can send you the screenshot of the output